# Getting Permission Denied running perl executables

Tags: perl, path, executable, permission-denied, bash

I am running OS X and, basically, I wanted to set up a directory where I could drop some Perl executables and use them without having to type

```
$perl /this/is/the/path/name.pl
```

every time I wanted to use one. So I modified my .bash_profile to add a filepath for a directory that sits on my desktop that I want to drop executables in. I modified my .bash_profile by adding

```
PATH=$PATH:/Users/Wes/Desktop/Perl_dir; export PATH
```

Now, it finds the Perl files I want but denies me permission to them like so

```
-bash: /Users/Wes/Desktop/Perl_dir/phylo.pl: Permission denied
```

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure that the perl script itself is set to be executable.  You can do this with a command like this:

```
chmod +x /Users/Wes/Desktop/Perl_dir/phylo.pl
```

And then make sure the first line of the script has an appropriate "hash-bang" line to invoke perl, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

With both of those in place, I think your scripts should start working.  (Note:  The `-w` isn't strictly necessary, and may cause warnings in your script.  I do suggest it, though, for developing new perl code, since it encourages a certain brand of perl hygiene.)

Comment: `-w` is not the same as `use warnings;`, and it's not necessarily going to be helpful to the OP to get warnings from his CPAN modules. I'd suggest removing that recommendation, and replacing it with a more general recommendation to always have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your scripts.

Comment: To be thorough: `chmod +x /Users/Wes/Desktop/Perl_dir/*.pl` ☺

Comment: @shawnhcorey IMO using glob with `chmod +x` is stepping to security "grey zone": I'd prefer the act of marking something as executable be always explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from setting PATH correctly, you also need to:

- make sure files are executable

  ```
  $ chmod +x /this/is/the/path/name.pl
  ```
- check your "shebang line", i.e. first line of the script must contain
  absolute path to perl interpreter on your machine, like this:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  # this will work in Linux distros
  ```

  To find out the path, use which command:

  ```
  $ which perl
  /path/to/perl
  ```

Answer (score -2):

you may need to authorize the chmod using sudo, try this:

```
sudo chmod u+x program_name
./program_name
```

If not sudo while chmod, you need to run like this:

```
sudo chmod u+x program_name
sudo ./program_name
```

Comment: The last example basically just runs the script as root, which is irrelevant (and totally a bad idea as general advice, although I admit I don't undersand what you mean by "If not sudo while chmod").